# How can I display a row with a certain value in its string selected?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm working in SSRS, and I am trying to figure out how to display a row if a certain value in its string is selected from the multiselect parameter. Let's say we have a table like this:

```
ID    Animals
-------------
 1    Cat, dog, bird
 2    Dog
 3    Dog, pig, Cat
```

Whenever I choose dog in my parameter, all 3 rows should display. If I were to select cat, only 2 rows should show. I've used the InStr function to show or hide a column before, but I'm not sure how to use it select the rows. I've tried `InStr(Fields!Animals.Value,"Dog")`, but it only brings that one line.

Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The difficulty you are experiencing is a result of storing multiple values in a single column, and why that should be avoided.  If you use LIKE clause with wildcards, you will find your data but if you have more than a handful of records performance will be slow.  This is a terrible design.

Comment: Well I split the function to begin with, but someone is asking if they select a certain value to pull back the additional values tagged with it. With the split, only dog would show rather than everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LIKE and use % on both sides of the word to indicate that you want to find 'Dog' anywhere in the string.

```
SELECT ID, Animals
FROM your_table
WHERE animals LIKE '%Dog%'
```

Comment: Assuming `Dog` is not a substring of something else

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
InStr(LCase(Fields!Animals.Value),"dog")
```

Since in SSRS `Dog` and `dog` is not the same, you have to low case your field.

This will work if you Animals field returns a string with names of multiple animals.

In this case:

`LCASE("Dog, pig, Cat")` will return `"dog, pig, cat"` you have to ensure that the string you want to search in the field is lower case too.